# gmap3: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I am developing a Wordpress website, and need to display an Google map in the contact page. But i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the JavaScript console. Here is the code, can anyone tell mere whats wrong?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".google-maps").gmap3({
    marker:{ 
        address:"511, amaliesgade, københavn",options:{icon: "img/marker.png"}
    },
    map:{
      options:{
        zoom: 14,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        scalControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true}
    }
    }); 
});
```

Thanks for your time, and thanks in advance

Troels

Comment: Did you include the google map JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en is included just before.

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress jQuery will run in no-conflict-mode, where you can't access jQuery directly via `$`.

Try this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
    $(".google-maps").gmap3({
    marker:{ 
        address:"511, amaliesgade, københavn",options:{icon: "img/marker.png"}
    },
    map:{
      options:{
        zoom: 14,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        scalControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true}
    }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Molle, Thats correct, unfortunately this is not the problem as my script starts with: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
But thanks anyway :)